# How to write schemaFunction in Jython for Apache Pig?

Tags: apache-pig, jython

How to write @schemaFunction of generic UDF in Jython for Apache Pig?
For example, how to define zipWithIndex function which takes an argument of a bag of an arbitrary tuples and returns a bag of tuples of int:index and the said tuple.

Answer (score 1):

This link might be helpful to solve your problem

```
https://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/on-writing-python-udf-for-pig-a-perspective/
```